# FullCalendar 6 and Bootstrap 5 : change tooltip background color

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, bootstrap-5, fullcalendar-6

My FullCalendar agenda has colored events. Now I want the tooltip to have the same background color. Yet the tooltip has always a black background. I can I change this dynamically with regards to event color ?

So far I tried this but the background remains black (although it used to work with FullCalendar 2.9 and Bootstrap 3) :

```
eventDidMount: function (arg) {

// SOme code

    var tooltipHtml = "<div style=\"background-color:" + arg.event.extendedProps.backgroundColor + ";" + "color:" + arg.event.extendedProps.textColor + ";" + "\">" +
                "<b>" arg.event.title 
                + "</b></div>";

     var tooltipOptions = {
                    "html": true, // Allows HTML in tooltips
                    "title": tooltipHtml,
                    "container": "body" // To avoid the tooltip being hidden by the header
                };


},
```

I read FullCalendar doc and set `themeSystem: 'bootstrap5', and imported bootstrap 5.3 bundle js and icons before FullCalendar.js.

I also read in Bootstrap doc that a [sanitizer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/) was used on the tooltip text :

> By default, this component uses the built-in content sanitizer, which strips out any HTML elements that are not explicitly allowed. See the sanitizer section in our JavaScript documentation for more details.

But the div tag is already in the list of allowed tags so I don't know what to add.

So how can I change the tooltip color for each event?

Note that the colors are defined by the user at runtime and are not known beforehand. So creating a custom class where I define the background color is not a solution although it achieves to change the background color of the tooltips.

**EDIT**
Passing `sanitize : false` to the [tooltip's options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/#options) makes the tooltip to be rendered as defined in tooltipHtml :

```
var tooltipOptions = {
                    "html": true, // Allows HTML in tooltips
                    "title": tooltipHtml,
                    "sanitize": false, //<-- Don't filter the html code in title
                    "container": "body" // To avoid the tooltip being hidden by the header
                };
```

So this is basically an issue related to how the html code contained in `title` is being filtered (sanitized). I will try and post the minimum `allowlist` I have to add to make it work so that sanitize is not completely disabled.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So as written in my EDIT in the original question my problem was related to the way Bootstrap tooltip sanitizes the `title` content.

As my title content (see `tooltipHtml`) was in a div, I had to add `style` in the `div` section of `defaultAllowList`. So at the top of my script I defined :

```
const myDefaultAllowList = bootstrap.Tooltip.Default.allowList;
myDefaultAllowList.div = ['style'];
```

And then in the `eventDidMount` method where I define the tooltip, I pass custom allowList :

```
var tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(arg.el, {
                html: true,
                title: tooltipHtml,
                placement: 'bottom', // Adjust the placement as needed
                trigger: 'hover', // Show the tooltip on hover
                allowList: myDefaultAllowList, // <--- Add this paremeter
            });
```

Obvisously if your title is for eg in a  tag you'll have to target b in your custom allow list : `myDefaultAllowList.b = ['style'];`

Now the tooltips background colors can be changed programmatically!